# Populating a multidimensional array of type any in a for loop

Tags: julia

I have defined a multidimensional array - `Multi_arr=Array{Any, 2}(undef, length(n), 6)`. The intent is to populate the array in a for-loop. When I try to access an element from the array, for example `Multi_arr[1,1]`; the following error is returned

```
UndefRefError: access to undefined reference

Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Array{Any,2}, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:732
 [2] top-level scope at In[106]:1
```

Is element access any different from regular arrays in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first assign a value of an element before trying to access it. Such situations are signaled by Julia by displaying `#undef` when showing the array, e.g.:

```
julia> Matrix{Any}(undef, 2, 3)
2×3 Array{Any,2}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef
```

This property has two benefits:

- it is fast to create such an array
- you can catch an error in your code (trying to access uninitialized location)

(note that `#undef` is a default value only for non-bits types)

You can check if a cell is `#undef` in such an array using `isassigned` function.

If you want to set some default non-informative value in an array that you will be able to read then pass `nothing` or `missing` instead of `undef`, e.g.:

```
julia> Matrix{Any}(nothing, 2, 3)
2×3 Array{Any,2}:
 nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing

julia> Matrix{Any}(missing, 2, 3)
2×3 Array{Any,2}:
 missing  missing  missing
 missing  missing  missing
```

Now you can read from such an array before assigning something (and probably then you should treat `nothing` or `missing` as a sentinel of no assignment).